# Unable to change Firebase password in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firefox, firebase-authentication

I am getting a weird error when I attempt to change a firebase password programatically. Everything works fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox.
The site is a React SPA and I'm using the firebase react module. The workflow is very simple. User enters email address and presses button. That calls to the firebase .sendPasswordResetEmail function. That sends the user an email that brings them back to the website to change it.
When the password reset page loads, I call:

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .verifyPasswordResetCode(this.props.oobCode)
  .then(email => {
    this.setState({ email });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.setState({ message: error.message });
  });
```

This properly verifies the oobCode. Then when the user enters two matching passwords, I call:

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .confirmPasswordReset(this.props.oobCode, passwordOne)
  .then(() => { alert('Password successfully changed') })
  .catch(e => {
    alert('Password was not changed.\n' + e.message);
  });
```

The error displayed is: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.

This works fine in Chrome (mobile and desktop), but not Firefox. Does anyone have any ideas of what modifications I need to make for it to work in Firefox???

Comment: Is there any ad-blocker or some plugins like that

Comment: and is there some log on the console

Comment: There's no pop up blocker. Also, the console doesn't show any error. I got the error mentioned by logging the catch of the promise